# exception to be logged in java

Tags: java, sonarqube

I am a newbie to the world of java and maybe asking a very debatable question that is from the exception logging best practices in mind I have the below code, please let me know is there anything wrong in it since when I scan this code against sonar qube it does  report the issues that exception must be either logged or rethrown

```
 public ResponseEntity<mainDTO> updateMain(@RequestBody mainDTO domainDTO)
            throws RNNotFoundException {
        try {
            return ResponseEntity.ok(mainService.update(mainDTO));
        } catch (RNNotFoundException e) {
            logger.error("Exception in updatemain"+ e.getMessage());
            throw e;
        }catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not use throws RNNotFoundException and try-catch blocks together.

If you are catching RNNotFoundException exception in the parent method from where you are calling updateMain you remove try-catch blocks here.

If you are not catching this exception from anywhere you remove throws RNNotFoundException.